# Discord.js dice roller problem returning (result+1)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, dice

I'm codding a discord bot and trying to implement a new dice code. I have this sketch:

```js
 //dice rolling
    if(command.match(/(\d+)d(\d+)([+-]\d+)?/)) {
        let total = 0;
        let individualRolls = [];
        const rolls = command.match(/(\d+)d(\d+)/g);
        for (let i = 0; i < rolls.length; i++) {
            const [count, size] = rolls[i].split("d").map(val => parseInt(val));
            for(let j=0; j<count; j++){
                let roll = (Math.floor(Math.random() * size) + 1);
                individualRolls.push(roll);
                total += roll;
            }
        }
        const modifier = command.match(/([+-]\d+)/);
        if (modifier) {
            total += Number(modifier[0]);
        }
        message.channel.send(`You rolled ${command} and got ${total}!\nIndividual rolls: ${individualRolls}`);
    }
```

It actually works but when I roll like `\*1d20+1d30` it gives a weird result. Let's suppose I've rolled a 20 and a 30, so the result should be 50, but the bot returns me 51, like the example below:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this or what's causing this?

Comment: It's because of the `modifier`. `modifier[0]` is `+1` and you add that to the total.

Comment: If i remove it, when I run *1d20+1d30 for example, it returns NaN (Not a number)

" You rolled 1d20+1d30 and got NaN!
Individual rolls: 19,17 "

Comment: I'm not really sure what that modifier is supposed to do. From the regex, it seems that you want to add or subtract something but I'm not sure what. Can you show me an example?

Comment: Sure. The idea is to roll a modifier with the dice. Lets suppose I roll 1d20+2. The final result will be the number on the d20+ the modifier. If I get 18, the final result will be a 20. Just that. This way it works but whent I type *1d20+1d100 for example it returns me the result + 1 and the problem really seems to be what you pointed but ir returns me NaN if removed. Later the idea is to roll like *1d20+1d100+1d30+(modifier), various dices and various modifiers, but this is getting too complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `modifier`. Your current regex matches `+1` in your command `*1d20+1d30` because it doesn't really care if `+1` is followed by the letter `d`. Check out the snippet below:

```js
let commands = ['*1d20+1d30', '*1d20+1d30+5', '*1d20+1d30-7'];
let regex = /([+-]\d+)/;

commands.forEach(command => {
  let modifier = command.match(regex);

  console.log(`${command}: ${modifier?.[0]}`);
});
```

If the `modifier` is only allowed to be at the end of the command, you can change your regex to only match the modifier if it's at the end. Adding the `$` sign after the capturing group makes sure it only matches modifiers at the end of the string: `/([+-]\d+)$/`.

```js
let commands = ['*1d20+1d30', '*1d20+1d30+5', '*1d20+1d30-7'];
let regex = /([+-]\d+)$/;

commands.forEach(command => {
  let modifier = command.match(regex);

  console.log(`${command}: ${modifier?.[0]}`);
});
```

You could also use negative lookahead to exclude the character `d` from your match: `/([+-]\d+)(?!d)/`. The negative lookahead (`?!`) asserts that the pattern following it doesn't match.

```js
let commands = ['*1d20+1d30', '*1d20+1d30+5', '*1d20+1d30-7'];
let regex = /([+-]\d+)(?!d)/;

commands.forEach(command => {
  let modifier = command.match(regex);

  console.log(`${command}: ${modifier?.[0]}`);
});
```

You can run the snippet below and see that now it works as expected:

```js
let command = '*1d20+2d10-3';
let total = 0;
let individualRolls = [];
let rolls = command.match(/(\d+)d(\d+)/g);

for (let i = 0; i < rolls.length; i++) {
  let [count, size] = rolls[i].split('d').map((val) => parseInt(val));

  for (let j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    let roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * size) + 1;
    individualRolls.push(roll);
    total += roll;
  }
}

let modifier = command.match(/([+-]\d+)(?!d)/);

if (modifier) {
  total += Number(modifier[0]);
}

console.log(`You rolled ${command} and got ${total}!
Individual rolls: ${individualRolls}
Modifier: ${modifier?.[0]}`);
```

Comment: MAN I WANT TO GIVE YOU A DAMN KISS

It worked, thanks a lot